# How to show different product based on url parameter using WordPress Woo-Commerce plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing e-commerce site using WordPress and Woo-Commerce plugin.

I am showing all product on the **package** page. This package page url will be something like this :

**www.mysite.com/package/?visa=bd**

**www.mysite.com/package/?visa=us**

**www.mysite.com/package/?visa=in**

Now based on this **bd** or **us** or **in** parameter I want to specific product.

Is this possible? If so, How can I do this ?

Big Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Within your settings there should be an option to set permalinks, these also control the WooCommerce links as well. You can change them to be activated by anything you would like.

Comment: May be you don't understand my question. My all product is showing on package page. This package page is url is : www.mysite.com/package/ but I modify it by adding a parameter because based on this parameter I want to different product. parameter value is bd or us or in.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. Within the permalinks tab there should be an option to be able to edit this.

WooCommerce allows you to change their routing based on the permalinks. If you edit those permalinks, you should be able to change the way it handles those parameters.